# Error - ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: errors, amsmath, gather

I'm new on latex, today I try to use de environment gather of the package "amsmath" but get the fallowing error:

> ```
> ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
>
> <template> }}\savetaglength@ \endtemplate 
>                                          
> l.173     \end{gather}
> ```

My source code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{paracol} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}   
...   
    \begin{gather} 
        40y - 2x + x + 2 &= 40 \\ 
        y &= \frac{38}{40} + x \\
        \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx, \; P(x) = y' + x 
    \end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Sorry for my English, I google the problem but the only things that i get its table errors that don't have relevant to this case.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The `gather`  environment doesn't align whatever: it centres each row, so don't use `&` with it. If you do want to align the `=` signs, use the `align` environment

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*gather* does not support alignment. You' ve got two choices. Either avoid alignment or use align environment.

In the former case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{paracol} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,mathtools}
\begin{document}  
\begin{gather} 
40y - 2x + x + 2 = 40 \\ 
y = \frac{38}{40} + x \\
\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx, \; P(x) =   y' + x 
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

whereas in the latter case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{paracol} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,mathtools}
\begin{document}  
\begin{gather}
  \begin{align*}
        40y - 2x + x + 2 &= 40 \\ 
        y &= \frac{38}{40} + x \\
        \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx, \; P(x) = y' + x 
  \end{align*}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]